# Correcting non-uniform illumination on light background - matlab

Tags: image, matlab, background

I am currently working on image segmentation using Threshold. I have tried both Otsu's method and Gonzalez's method. So what I did is this:

```
% Apply different threshold methods
otsu_thresh = graythresh(I);
[bw, gw_thresh] = threshold_gw(I);

I_OT = im2bw(I, otsu_thresh);
I_G = im2bw(I, gw_thresh/255);
```

Now, the results I get are shown below:
[image]

As you can see I am having some problems with Otsu's thresholding and I am assuming that is because of Non Uniform background illumination.
I have followed this example:
http://www.mathworks.nl/help/images/examples/correcting-nonuniform-illumination.html
on correcting Non Uniform Illumination, but unfortunately in all the examples the background is dark and the objects are whiter so they do imopen and then substract the background.

In my case, the background is lighter than the objects so I performed imclose instead. Now I have the background:
[image]

The problem comes when I try to subtract this background from the original image everything becomes black. This makes sense since the objects are already black (so value 0). 
I can't find any method to subtract the background and keep the objects. Anyone has an idea on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a technique called Adaptive Thresholding, or alternatively use the Triangle Method for thresholding.

Also, if you substract the background from itself, of course you get black! Indeed, you want to substract the amount of blackness, which is `1-x` with `x` the pixel value (or 255-x in the case of integer image).

To substract the amount of blackness, use

```
newimage = 1 - ((1-oldimage)-(1-background));
```

Simplification is left as an exercise for the reader...

Answer (score 0):

According to your reasoning, the objects are darker than the background. Thus, once you estimated the color of the background (nice result BTW) you can simply

```
BW = origImage < backgroundImage;
```

This will give you `BW` with `true` on the objects and `false` everywhere else.
If you want to keep the objects dark (`false`) and set everything elese to `true` then

```
BW = origImage > backgroundImage;
```